# How to create clickable /touchable Xamarin WebView

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios

I am developing iOS and Android application on Xamarin Forms.

I am using WebView in my project. I want to hide *ActivityIndicator* on the application when this *WebView* element is clicked.

The only thing I need is; run a method by clicking on the WebView element.

**The codes I've tried;**

[xamarin.forms Handle Clicked event on WebView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30397090/xamarin-forms-handle-clicked-event-on-webview) (Didn't work)

[Calling a C# function through Javascript onClick event in WebView in Xamarin.Forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51430238/calling-a-c-sharp-function-through-javascript-onclick-event-in-webview-in-xamari) (Not Working)

**XAML**

```
<StackLayout HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
            <ActivityIndicator x:Name="PageLoader" IsRunning="true" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"></ActivityIndicator>
            <local:Webview21 Navigated="LoadedPage" IsVisible="false" x:Name="MainContent" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
            </local:Webview21>
</StackLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Cause:**

Click action will conflict with native JS action.

**Solution:**

You can use CustomRenderer to add a `TapGestureRecognizer` and  let webview recognize it.Then use `MessagingCenter` to pass notification when you click the webview.Refer to the following code.

> in Forms

```
using System;
using Xamarin.Forms;
namespace xxx
{
    public class MyWebView:WebView
    {
        public MyWebView()
        {
        }
    }
}
```

> in iOS project

```
using System;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS;

using UIKit;
using Foundation;
using ObjCRuntime;

[assembly:ExportRenderer(typeof(MyWebView),typeof(MyWebViewRenderer))]
namespace xxx.iOS
{
    public class MyWebViewRenderer:WebViewRenderer, IUIGestureRecognizerDelegate
    {
        public MyWebViewRenderer()
        {
        }

        protected override void OnElementChanged(VisualElementChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            if(NativeView!=null)
            {
                UITapGestureRecognizer tapGestureRecognizer = new UITapGestureRecognizer(this, new Selector("HandleTap:"))
                {
                    WeakDelegate = this,
                    CancelsTouchesInView = false
                };
                NativeView.AddGestureRecognizer(tapGestureRecognizer);
            }

        }

        [Export("gestureRecognizer:shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:")]
        public bool ShouldRecognizeSimultaneously(UIGestureRecognizer gestureRecognizer, UIGestureRecognizer otherGestureRecognizer)
        {
            return true;
        }

        [Export("HandleTap:")]
        void HandleTap(UITapGestureRecognizer tap)
        {
            MessagingCenter.Send<Object>(this,"webviewClicked");
        }

    }
}
```

> in Android Project

```
using System;
using Android.Content;
using Android.Webkit;

using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android;

[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(MyWebView), typeof(MyWebViewRenderer))]
namespace xxx.Droid
{
    public class MyWebViewRenderer:WebViewRenderer
    {
        public MyWebViewRenderer(Context context):base(context)
        {

        }

        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Xamarin.Forms.WebView> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            if(Control!=null)
            {
                Control.SetWebViewClient(new MyWebviewClient());
                Control.Touch+= (object sender, TouchEventArgs eventArgs) => {


                    if(eventArgs.Event.Action==Android.Views.MotionEventActions.Down)
                    {
                        MessagingCenter.Send<Object>(this, "webviewClicked");
                    }



                };

            }

        }

    }


    internal class MyWebviewClient: WebViewClient
    {
        public override bool ShouldOverrideUrlLoading(Android.Webkit.WebView view, IWebResourceRequest request)
        {
            return true;
        }
    }



}
```

Now you can hide the `ActivityIndi​​cator` when you click the webview

> in xxxpage.xaml

```
<StackLayout HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
            <ActivityIndicator x:Name="PageLoader" IsRunning="true" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"></ActivityIndicator>
            <local:MyWebView Source="xxx"  IsVisible="true" x:Name="MainContent" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
            </local:MyWebView>
</StackLayout>
```

> in code behind

```
public partial class xxxPage : ContentPage
    {

        public xxxPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            MessagingCenter.Subscribe<Object>(this, "webviewClicked", (obj) =>
            {

                // you can hide the ActivityIndi​​cator here.

            });

        }

    }
```

Comment: You are great! That worked now! Thanks so much. You saved my life and time.

Comment: Happy coding :)

Comment: Hi again @Lucas Zhang - MSFT
 :) Android Renderer has a problem. Webview's scrolling not working when i use custom Android renderer. Thanks again.

Comment: Ok. I will check it

Comment: I fixed it. Thanks.

'switch (eventArgs.Event.Action)
                        {
                            case Android.Views.MotionEventActions.Down:
                                Control.Parent.RequestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
                                break;
                            case Android.Views.MotionEventActions.Up:
                                Control.Parent.RequestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(false);
                                break;
                        }'